# SQL Server : create view if not exists don't work

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying create view if not exist using:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.zestaw_zam_fak') IS NULL 
   CREATE VIEW AS 
       SELECT .... 
       FROM .... 
       UNION 
       SELECT ..... 
       FROM.... 
       UNION 
       SELECT ... 
       FROM ...
```

But I get an error:

> Unable to parse query text
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword VIEW.

Without statement  `'IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.zestaw_zam_fak') IS NULL`, the view is created correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `dbo.zestaw_zam_fak` is this a view name?

Answer (score 4):

You have to wrap the `CREATE` statement into `EXEC('your create statement')`. Otherwise it won't work in `IF`

**EXAMPLE:**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.vwCity') IS NULL
BEGIN   
    EXECUTE('CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwCity]
    AS
    SELECT  *
    FROM  dbo.City')
END
```

Answer (score 2):

```
IF Object_ID('dbo.TestView') IS NOT NULL
    DROP VIEW dbo.TestView;

GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.TestView
   as

SELECT 1 AS Col1;
```

Alternatively, you can use Dynamic SQL.

Comment: @Vikrant, that one is not fully correct. They missed to put GO between IF and CREATE, that's why I provided the right one instead of giving the link to incorrect answer.

Comment: @Vikrant LOL Your comment is also from that answer and the answer is given - re-apply the permission script.  If you plan to create a view and add the permissions, then just drop, recreate and apply permissions. If not, just drop and recreate. I don't see the problem here.